# Count over PySpark dataframe by Running-window using a combination of two columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rolling-computation

I have a spark DataFrame (v.2.2.0) in which I want to count (by a group key) all events that occurred within a certain time-frame, for example, 5-day from the *start_date* of the event in each row to the *end_date* of the other rows. So for example

```
# For the sake of simplicity I included only 1 user, but there are multiple users
+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|end_date           |start_date         |uid  |
+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|2020-11-26 09:30:28|2020-11-26 08:30:22|user1|
|2020-11-26 10:41:00|2020-11-26 10:00:00|user1|
|2020-11-22 12:40:27|2020-11-22 08:37:18|user1|
|2020-11-22 15:22:20|2020-11-22 13:32:30|user1|
|2020-11-20 17:20:07|2020-11-20 16:04:04|user1|
```

I defined a window

```
days = lambda i: i * 86400 # 60*60*24 = number of seconds in a day
w = (Window()
   .partitionBy(col("uid"))
   .orderBy(col("end_date").cast("timestamp").cast("long"))
   .rangeBetween(-days(5), 0))
```

And I calculated over the window:

```
by_end = df.select(col("start_date"), f.count("end_date").over(w).alias("count"))
df = df.join(by_end, 'start_date', how='left')
```

I'll get this:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+-----+-------+
|end_date           |start_date         |uid  |count  |
+-------------------+-------------------+-----+-------+
|2020-11-26 09:30:28|2020-11-26 08:30:22|user1|  4    |
|2020-11-26 10:41:00|2020-11-26 10:00:00|user1|  3    |
|2020-11-22 12:40:27|2020-11-22 08:37:18|user1|  3    |
|2020-11-22 15:22:20|2020-11-22 13:32:30|user1|  2    |
|2020-11-20 17:20:07|2020-11-20 16:04:04|user1|  1    |
```

But, to my understanding, this will do the rolling-window count by end-date, which is almost correct, since I need it from the *start_date* of current event to the *end_date* of all others.

Any suggestions?